# HTML/CSS Newsletter, @media query not resizing text on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, media

For whatever reason my text resizing is not working on iPhones, working fine on android, and in another email format. Can't seem to see any differences between the two files. The images also resize, seems to just be an issue with the text.

```
<head>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Outlook link fix */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    /* Hotmail background & line height fixes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100% !important;}
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
    /* Image borders & formatting */
    img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} 
    a img {border:none;} 
    /* Re-style iPhone automatic links (eg. phone numbers) */
    .applelinks a {color:#222222; text-decoration: none;}
    /* Hotmail symbol fix for mobile devices */
    .ExternalClass img[class^=Emoji] { width: 10px !important; height: 10px !important; display: inline !important; } 


    /* Media Query for mobile */

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {  

    /* This resizes tables and images to be 100% wide with a proportionate width */
    table[class=emailwrapto100pc], img[class=emailwrapto100pc]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}

    /* Hide stuff on mobiles */
    table[class=emailnomob],td[class=emailnomob],img[class=emailnomob],span[class=emailnomob]{display:none !important;}

    td[class=emailcolsplit]{width:100%!important; float:left!important;}

    a[class=emailmobbutton]{display:block !important;font-size:14px !important; font-weight:bold !important; padding:6px 4px 8px 4px !important; line-height:18px !important; background:#dddddd !important; margin:10px auto;width:100%; text-align:center; color:#111 !important; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:#fff 1px 0 0 ;}

    /* This resizes body text for mobiles */
    span[class=emailbodytext],a[class=emailbodytext]{font-size:16px !important; line-height:21px !important;}
    }

    @media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    a[class=emailmobbutton]{display: none !important;}
    span[class=emailmobbutton]{display: none !important;}
    }
```

```
                    <table style="padding-top:20px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" target="_blank">
                            <img height="216" width="216" border="0" src="" style="display: block;" class="emailwrapto100pc" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td align="center" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                            <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: #111111">               
                            <span class="emailbodytext" style="font-size:12px; font-family:tahoma, sans-serif; line-height:20px; color:#333333;">Hugo Boss Black</span>
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
                            <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: #111111">
                            <span class="emailbodytext" style="font-size:12px; font-family:tahoma, sans-serif; line-height:20px; color:#333333;">Bugnara Polo T-Shirt</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="33%">
                        <a style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; padding:5px 20px; font-family:tahoma, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;" href="">
                            SHOP NOW</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the viewport meta data on your header?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Comment: Add also this to your css link: media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: Yes, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> and my css link <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />, I guess it can't be displayed in a code block. Will try media screen now

Comment: What E-Mail clients do you use on the different devices?

Comment: Native on Android and iPhone, did not have this issue on a previous email layout. At least for my eyes everything is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into an issue where I was working with email provider that did not allow modifications in 
    `<head>` 
section, and my one 
    `<style> @media ...</style>` code did not work.

With email we have to think back rather than forward in time. Try writing you media query as a separate block section. I've tried this method & it worked without a hitch on Android, where the previous method failed.

```
`<style type="text/css">
/* standard styles */
</style>
<style media="screen and (max-width: 480px)">
/* responsive styles */
</style>`
```

Hope this helps you out.